# Concatenate columns and rows

Tags: sql

Given a table, e.g.:

Table `Person`:

```
id, name, last_name, age

1, joshua,  smith,  33
2, melissa, fox,    65
3, james,   bond,   31
...
```

I have to read each row from the table, get  the current row, concat its column name and value and then, finally, put them into another table as new rows. E.g:

Column `concat_row` (varchar) in new table:

```
"name: joshua, last_name: smith, age: 33"
"name: melissa, last_name: fox, age: 65"
"name: james, last_name: bond, age: 31"
...
```

The point is, I need to use a generic query where I shouldn't know how many columns there are or what are their names, because this query will be used with hundreds of tables... So, it could be interesting modifying only the table name for each case.

Comment: Typically something like `select * into newtable from yourtable` would suffice.  However, if you don't know the columns and want to combine them together into a single column, you'll need to use `dynamic sql` with some `concat` function (depending on your database).

Comment: If you use SQL Server check out the [FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms178107.aspx)

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Perhaps some product specific functionality can be used. Otherwise, dynamic SQL is my number one tip.

Comment: sgeddes, cha, jarlh, thanxs for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below SQL and extend it per your need,

```
USE AdventureWorks2014

DECLARE @OwnerName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TblName VARCHAR(50)

SET @OwnerName = 'Sales'
SET @TblName = 'Customer'

DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Columns = ''

SELECT @Columns = @Columns + ('''' + Column_Name + ':'' + ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR(MAX),' + Column_Name + '),'''')   + '',  '' + ')
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TblName
    ) A

--PRINT @Columns

DECLARE @FinalSelect VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @FinalSelect = 'Select ' + LEFT(@Columns, LEN(@Columns) - 10) + ' Contact_Row From ' + @OwnerName + '.' + @TblName

--print  @FinalSelect
EXEC (@FinalSelect)
```

And the output is (Top 5 rows),

> CustomerID:1,  PersonID:,  StoreID:934,  TerritoryID:1, 
>   AccountNumber:AW00000001, 
>   rowguid:3F5AE95E-B87D-4AED-95B4-C3797AFCB74F,  ModifiedDate:Sep 12
>   2014 11:15AM CustomerID:2,  PersonID:,  StoreID:1028,  TerritoryID:1, 
>   AccountNumber:AW00000002, 
>   rowguid:E552F657-A9AF-4A7D-A645-C429D6E02491,  ModifiedDate:Sep 12
>   2014 11:15AM CustomerID:3,  PersonID:,  StoreID:642,  TerritoryID:4, 
>   AccountNumber:AW00000003, 
>   rowguid:130774B1-DB21-4EF3-98C8-C104BCD6ED6D,  ModifiedDate:Sep 12
>   2014 11:15AM CustomerID:4,  PersonID:,  StoreID:932,  TerritoryID:4, 
>   AccountNumber:AW00000004, 
>   rowguid:FF862851-1DAA-4044-BE7C-3E85583C054D,  ModifiedDate:Sep 12
>   2014 11:15AM CustomerID:5,  PersonID:,  StoreID:1026,  TerritoryID:4, 
>   AccountNumber:AW00000005, 
>   rowguid:83905BDC-6F5E-4F71-B162-C98DA069F38A,  ModifiedDate:Sep 12
>   2014 11:15AM

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! I tested it making some changes (in order to adapt it to my schema, quotes needs and table names) and it worked just beautifully. A very friend of mine told me I must trust this site. Thaxs again man.

Comment: @Ges, Glad to help, Any time... Do a UP vote. So that others also can consume the same set.

Comment: maybe because I'm new here, they don't allow me to give a UP vote (+1), I've marked the check of acceptance of the answer but I don't know how to do the other thing...